# The asymptotic of the number of integers that are sums of three nonnegative cubes

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, asymptotics, cubics

Let $c(n) $ be the number of distinct integers between $0 $ and $n $ of the form $ a^3 + b^3 + c^3$, meaning the sum of $3$ nonnegative cubes.

$C(n) = O( n \space \ln(n)^x ) $

Find and prove the optimal real value of $x$.

Comment: There are only $n+1$ distinct integers between $0$ and $n$, so $0 \le C(n) \le n+1$, and thus, $C(n)$ is $O(n)$. Hence, $x = 0$ works. Did you mean to ask for the minimum value of $x$ such that $C(n)$ is $O(n (\ln n)^x)$?

Comment: I added the word optimal Jimmy ... I mean best asymptotic. Is it clear now ?

Comment: ^Yes, now the problem doesn't have a trivial answer. :)

Comment: See [OEIS A$003072$](https://oeis.org/A003072).

Comment: Can someone please give an argument why it is expected that $C(n)=O\left(n\,\big(\ln(n)\big)^x\right)$, and not $C(n)=O\left(n^{1-\epsilon}\right)$ for some $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: This is a hard problem and there is numerical evidence that the sum of three cubes actually has a positive density $\approx 0.0999425$ (ref: [On the Density of Sums of Three Cubes](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11792086_11) ).

Comment: You can  also find [some approximations here](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matdw/20150506sum3cub2.pdf)

Comment: @elaqqad the paper mentions a conditional result ( O(x^(1-eps)) ) based on a RH like conjecture of An assosiated L-function.  WHAT function ?? L-fucntion of An elliptic curve ??

Comment: Another wasted bounty ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

The amount of cubes lower than or equal to $n$ is $\lfloor\sqrt[3]{n}\rfloor$.
If we just have $A^3+B^3$ instead of $A^3+B^3+C^3$ we get:
$$C(n)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt[3]{n-1}\rfloor}\lfloor\sqrt[3]{n-i^3}\rfloor$$
And for $A^3+B^3+C^3$ (which is the result you want):
$$C(n)=\dfrac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt[3]{n-2}\rfloor}\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt[3]{n-i^3-1}\rfloor}\lfloor\sqrt[3]{n-i^3-j^3}\rfloor$$
This formula basically  just checks whether there exists a $C$ for every combination of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Looks like you might be able to convert this into a Riemann sum for a double integral of the form $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}} \sqrt[3]{1-x^3-y^3} dy\,dx$. This, of course, ignores the integer parts.

Comment: @ marty : what about that integral ? What does it give ?